google.sheets not defined node Google Sheets API
I had the following error and thought I'd share my solution as I couldn't find it online.
My initial code:
import * as google from 'googleapis';
const sheetsAPI = google.sheets({
    version: 'v4',
    auth: apiKey
});

Gave me the error:
google.sheets is not a function
My solution was rather using the following:
const sheetsAPI = new google.sheets_v4.Sheets({
    auth: apiKey
});

This ran correctly as the available guides said the code in the question would.
I'm going to accept my own answer once available, but would love to hear why I could be getting this problem in the first place if the docs for such a big platform told me to use the initial code?

My solution was rather using the following:
const sheetsAPI = new google.sheets_v4.Sheets({
    auth: apiKey
});

This ran correctly as the available guides said the code in the question would.

You need to install and import googleapis
To install:
npm install googleapis
# or
yarn add googleapis

Then import it as :
const {google} = require('googleapis');

or
import { google } from 'googleapis';

If you are using ECMAScript modules.
